# Which of these sentences is correct?

Tags: grammar, be, conjugation

Which wording is correct?

> "She will be graduated from the school on 16/0672023."

> "She will graduated from the school on 16/06/2023."

> "She will be graduating from the school on  16/06/2023.

Answer (score 1):

The most "natural-sounding" one that is also the simplest would be:

> She will graduate from the school on 16/06/2023.

Meanwhile, your third version is not wrong, but it is not necessary to use the future continuous (depending on your preceding sentences).

PS — Also depending on your preceding sentence(s), I would say you should write the sentence as,

> She will graduate from [Name of School] on 16/06/2023.

or

> She will graduate from there on 16/06/2023.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, the question of "will + be v-ing" versus "will + verb" (future continuous/progressive versus simple future) has been asked multiple times on here, so you can probably find more clarification with just a slight bit more of research.

Answer (score 0):

3 is applicable if you think of "graduating" is an act of moving from one status to another. An intransitive verb.

You have not suggested "She will graduate", which would have the same effect.

1 is applicable if you think of "graduation" as a status which is conferred by others. A verb in the passive mood. Most appropriate, perhaps, for the actual ceremony.

2 is simply 1 with the word "be" omitted, so that one is an error.